# How to count italicized words in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The script runs, but says the count is zero.

```
function countitaliccells() {
  var book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = book.getActiveSheet();
  var range_input = sheet.getRange("A2:F100"); 
  var range_output = sheet.getRange("G7");
  var cell_styles = range_input.getFontStyle(); // getFontStyle can only return 'italic' or 'normal'
  var count = 0;

  for(var r = 0; r < cell_styles.length; r++) {
    for(var c = 0; c < cell_styles[0].length; c++) { // isBold is a method for Google Documents only (not sheets) 
      if(cell_styles[r][c] === "italic") { // you need at least two '=' signs // also include the index of cell_styles
        count = count + 1; // count += 1 would also work
      }
    }
  }
  range_output.setValue(count); // make sure you setValue only when booth loops are done.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to count the cells including the bold font in the cels "A2:F100" of the active sheet.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function countitaliccells() {
  var book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = book.getActiveSheet();
  var range_input = sheet.getRange("A2:F100");
  var range_output = sheet.getRange("G7");
  var cell_styles = range_input.getFontWeights(); // Modified
  var count = 0;
  for (var r = 0; r < cell_styles.length; r++) {
    for (var c = 0; c < cell_styles[0].length; c++) {
      if (cell_styles[r][c] != "normal") {
        count = count + 1;
      }
    }
  }
  range_output.setValue(count);
}
```

- By this modification, the number of the cells including the bold font is retrieved.

#### Note:

- As additional information, in your script, I think that it is required to modify as follows.

  - From:

    ```
      var cell_styles = range_input.getFontStyle();
    ```
  - To:

    ```
      var cell_styles = range_input.getFontStyles();
    ```
- If you want to count both bold and italic, how about the following modification? In this modification, both the bold and the italic are counted. So, when you use `range_output.setValue(res.bold);`, the result of bold is put into cell "G7". When you use `range_output.setValue(res.italic);`, the result of italic is put into cell "G7".

  ```js
  function sample() {
    var book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = book.getActiveSheet();
    var range_input = sheet.getRange("A2:F100");
    var range_output = sheet.getRange("G7");

    // I modified the below script.
    var cell_styles = range_input.getTextStyles();
    var res = cell_styles.reduce((o, r) => {
      r.forEach(c => {
        if (c.isBold()) {
          o.bold++;
        }
        if (c.isItalic()) {
          o.italic++;
        }
      });
      return o;
    }, {bold: 0, italic: 0});
    range_output.setValue(res.bold); // or range_output.setValue(res.italic);
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [getFontWeights()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontweights)
- [getFontStyles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontstyles)
- [getTextStyles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#gettextstyles)

Comment: thank you I wasn't clear. I just wanted to count italic ones. Anyway I adjusted your function and it worked!

Comment: @Jonathan Ish-shalom About `thank you I wasn't clear. I just wanted to count italic ones. Anyway I adjusted your function and it worked!`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different approach from Tanaike.  You say you want to count words. If there are words within a sentence that are italicized, using font style or font weight will not work.  Using Rich Text you are assured of getting all italics.  This could easily be modified to only count if a cell contains an italic word.

I have this sheet:

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function countItalics() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Test2");
    let richText = sheet.getDataRange().getRichTextValues();
    let fontStyles = sheet.getDataRange().getFontStyles();
    console.log(fontStyles);
    let fontWeights = sheet.getDataRange().getFontWeights();
    console.log(fontWeights);
    let count = 0;
    richText.forEach( row => {
        row.forEach( cell => {
            let runs = cell.getRuns();
            runs.forEach( run => {
                let start = run.getStartIndex();
                let end = run.getEndIndex();
                let style = run.getTextStyle(start,end);
                if( style.isItalic() ) {
                  let text = run.getText().trim();
                  let words = text.split(" ");
                  count = count+words.length;
                }
              }
            );
          }
        );
      }
    );
    console.log(count);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in contItalics: "+err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
5:27:15 AM  Notice  Execution started
5:27:16 AM  Info    [ [ 'italic', 'normal' ],
  [ 'normal', 'normal' ],
  [ 'normal', 'normal' ] ]
5:27:17 AM  Info    [ [ 'normal', 'normal' ],
  [ 'normal', 'normal' ],
  [ 'normal', 'normal' ] ]
5:27:17 AM  Info    6
5:27:17 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- [Range.getRichTextValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getRichTextValues())
- [RichTextValue.getRuns()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value#getRuns())
- [RichTextValue.getTextStyle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value#getTextStyle(Integer,Integer))
- [TextStyle.isItalic()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-style#isItalic())